# react router - did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

when i click on the **Link**, it takes me to the right router in the URL but it says it did not match any routes. im super confused.

```
const rows = surveyList.map((survey) => {
    return(<tr key={survey[0].Id}>
            <td>{survey[0].Name}</td>
            <td>
                <Link className="links glyphicon glyphicon-edit" to={`surveydetail/${survey[0].Id}`} onClick={editSurvey}></Link>
            </td>
            <td>{survey[0].Entity}</td>
            <td>{ getSurveyTypeDescription(survey[0].Type)}</td>
        </tr>);
});
```

this is the routes.js file.`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import EditSurveyPage from './components/survey/EditSurveyPage';
import SurveyMaintenancePage from './components/survey/SurveyMaintenancePage';


export default (
    <Route path="SurveyMaintenance" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={SurveyMaintenancePage}/>
        <Route path="surveydetail/:id" component={EditSurveyPage} />
    </Route>
);
```

[image]

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

className not properly working in Link.Instead use NavLink.